# Thousand separator in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have changed Value on Data labels to None in Display units, but I want the numbers to appear like this 100 000 and not this 100000 as thousand separator.

[image]

How do I change the format in the visual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type ### ### ### in the format input field for the column or measure.

[image]

[image]